# Chi squared test of homogeneity

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

Suppose you want to test the null hypothesis:

H0: p1 = 0.65, p2 = 0.27, p3 = 0.01, p4 = 0.05, p5 = 0.02

to determine whether a population's distribution matches the proposed proportions.  You acquire a random sample of 100 individuals.  If the null hypothesis were true, what is the expected value of the test statistic?

I'm not sure I conceptually/intuitively understand how the chi-squared works.  Can someone elaborate on why the answer is 4 here?  If the null hypothesis is true, then the population does have proportions equal to 0.65, 0.27, 0.01, etc.  So what does this tell us of the test statistic?

Comment: If this is related to some subject, could you add the `self-study` tag please?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, if the sample proportions *exactly* matched the proposed proportions, $\chi^2$ would be 0. But there will be random fluctuation.

e.g.

```
set.seed(239920)
(testmult <- rmultinom(1, 100, c(0.65, 0.27, 0.01, 0.05, 0.02)))
```

does not yield exactly 65, 27, 1, 5, 2.

On repeated draws, the expected value of $\frac{(O-E)^2}{E}$ will be the degrees of freedom, which in this case is 4.

Comment: there is a typo in your statistic, the square is on the top, not bottom